# Customize JSON created by CL_SXML_STRING_WRITER

Tags: json, abap, json-serialization

I create JSON like this to extract any table (name "randomly" decided at runtime, its name is in variable `iv_table_name`):

```
FIELD-SYMBOLS <itab> TYPE STANDARD TABLE.
DATA ref_itab TYPE REF TO data.

DATA(iv_table_name) = 'SCARR'.
CREATE DATA ref_itab TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF (iv_table_name).
ASSIGN ref_itab->* TO <itab>.

SELECT *
  INTO TABLE <itab>
  FROM (iv_table_name).

DATA results_json TYPE TABLE OF string.
DATA sub_json TYPE string.

DATA(lo_json_writer) = cl_sxml_string_writer=>create( type = if_sxml=>co_xt_json ).

CALL TRANSFORMATION id
        SOURCE result = <itab>
        RESULT XML lo_json_writer.

cl_abap_conv_in_ce=>create( )->convert( 
        EXPORTING
          input = lo_json_writer->get_output( )
        IMPORTING
          data = sub_json ).
```

The result variable `sub_json` looks like this:

```
{"RESULT":
 [
   {"MANDT":"220","AUFNR":"0000012", ...},
   {"MANDT":"220","AUFNR":"0000013", ...},
   ...
  ]
}
```

Is there a way to avoid the surrounding dictionary and get the result like this?

```
 [
   {"MANDT":"220","AUFNR":"0000012", ...},
   {"MANDT":"220","AUFNR":"0000013", ...},
   ...
  ]
```

## Background:

I used this:

```
sub_json = /ui2/cl_json=>serialize( data = <lt_result> pretty_name = /ui2/cl_json=>pretty_mode-low_case ).
```

But the performance of `/ui2/cl_json=>serialize(  )` is not good.

Comment: Probably just with another transformation. I will post my proposal when I have some more time.

Comment: You can do it the KISS way by just removing the start and end parts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got no answer whether it's possible to omit the initial "RESULT" tag in full sXML, but my opinion is NO.

Now, there's the solution with the [KISS principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) :

```
REPLACE ALL OCCURRENCES OF REGEX '^\{"RESULT":|\}$' IN sub_json WITH ``.
```

There's also this other writing (slightly slower):

```
sub_json = replace( val = sub_json regex = '^\{"RESULT":|\}$' with = `` occ = 0 ).
```

ADDENDUM about performance:

I measured that for a string of 880K characters, the following code with the exact number of positions to remove (10 leading characters and 1 trailing character) is 6 times faster than regex (could vary based on version of ABAP kernel), but maybe it won't be noticeable compared to the rest of the program:

```
SHIFT sub_json LEFT BY 10 PLACES CIRCULAR.
REPLACE SECTION OFFSET strlen( sub_json ) - 11 OF sub_json WITH ``.
```

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to use it just as a tool for extracting table records then you could write your own `ID` transformation in `STRANS`. It could look like that, let us name it `Z_JSON_TABLE_CONTENTS` (create it with type `XSLT`):

```
<xsl:transform version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:sap="http://www.sap.com/sapxsl"
>

<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8" />

<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="RESULT">
  [
    <xsl:for-each select="*">
      {
      <xsl:for-each select="*">
        &quot;<xsl:value-of select="local-name()" />&quot;: &quot;<xsl:value-of select="text()" />&quot;<xsl:if test="position() != last()">,</xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each>
      }<xsl:if test="position() != last()">,</xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
  ]
</xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

Then you could use it like that.

```
REPORT ZZZ.

FIELD-SYMBOLS <itab> TYPE STANDARD TABLE.
DATA ref_itab TYPE REF TO data.

DATA(iv_table_name) = 'SCARR'.
CREATE DATA ref_itab TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF (iv_table_name).
ASSIGN ref_itab->* TO <itab>.

SELECT *
  INTO TABLE <itab>
  FROM (iv_table_name).

DATA results_json TYPE TABLE OF string.
DATA sub_json TYPE string.

DATA g_string TYPE string.
DATA(g_document) = cl_ixml=>create( )->create_document( ).
DATA(g_ref_stream_factory) = cl_ixml=>create( )->create_stream_factory( ).
DATA(g_ostream) = g_ref_stream_factory->create_ostream_cstring( g_string ).

CALL TRANSFORMATION Z_JSON_TABLE_CONTENTS
        SOURCE result = <itab>
        RESULT XML g_ostream.

DATA(g_json_parser) = new /ui5/cl_json_parser( ).
g_json_parser->parse( g_string ).
```

Answer (score 1):

Just a bit of manual work and voila!

```
DATA(writer) = CAST if_sxml_writer( cl_sxml_string_writer=>create( type = if_sxml=>co_xt_json ) ).

DATA(components) =
CAST cl_abap_structdescr( cl_abap_typedescr=>describe_by_name( iv_table_name ) )->components.

writer->open_element( name = 'object' ).
LOOP AT <itab> ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(<line>).
 LOOP AT components ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(<fs_comp>).
  ASSIGN COMPONENT <fs_comp>-name OF STRUCTURE <line> TO FIELD-SYMBOL(<fs_val>).
  writer->open_element( name = 'str' ).
  writer->write_attribute( name = 'name' value = CONV string( <fs_comp>-name ) ).
  writer->write_value( CONV string( <fs_val> ) ).
  writer->close_element( ).
 ENDLOOP.
ENDLOOP.
writer->close_element( ).

DATA(xml_json) = CAST cl_sxml_string_writer( writer )->get_output(  ).  
sub_json = cl_abap_codepage=>convert_from( source = xml_json codepage = `UTF-8` ).
```

No surrounding list and no dictionary. If you wanna each line in separate dictionary it is easily adjustable.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `ID` call transformation, then what ever node you give at transformation that node will be added by default. We cannot skip this but you can remove following way..

**Replace**: Using Regex or Direct word with Replace First Occurrence statement and next last closing brace `}`. The way you did.

**FIND**: You can simple use this below statement
`FIND REGEX '(\[.*\])' in sub_json SUBMATCHES sub_json.`

Comment: Additionally, your FIND statement is equivalent to this assignment with the `match` function: `sub_json = match( val = sub_json regex = '\[.*\]' ).`